# How to make a generic TypeVar in mypy be non-Optional?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

Is it possible to require a `TypeVar` in mypy to only resolve to non-`Optional` types? E.g.

```
from typing import Callable, Optional, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import Protocol


T = TypeVar('T')

def mapper(callabl: Callable[..., T]) -> T:
    return callabl()

def bad_function() -> Optional[int]:
    return None

mapper(reveal_type(bad_function))
```

In this example, `bad_function` is revealed to be of type `def () -> Union[builtins.int, None]`. I would like a way to restrict `T` to be bound to any type that's not optional (that is, not a `Union` with `None`), such that this code snippet would fail to type check. Other checkers like Typescript (and Kotlin's builtin type system) support this by default so I was wondering if it's possible to do in mypy as well. I know that it's possible to bind `TypeVar`s, but I couldn't figure out what would be the right thing to bind `T` to in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude type in Python typing annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854871/exclude-type-in-python-typing-annotation)