# How to handle incorrect type hint warning from Pylance when a function can have different return types?

Tags: python, python-typing, pylance

I have a Python function whose return type varies depending on the values of the arguments. Pylance type-checking seems to require that subsequent usages handle all possible types. This might be reasonable, but it would be nice if it could deduce the type when possible. However, what is the proper/clean way to suppress this warning if the type is known from a programmer's perspective?

This is a small example illustrating the issue:

```
def f(x: int):
    return 1 if x == 0 else "foo"

def g(x: int):
    print(x)

g(f(0))
```

with the reported Pylance error:

```
Argument of type "Literal[1, 'foo']" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "int" in function "g"
  Type "Literal[1, 'foo']" cannot be assigned to type "int"
    "Literal['foo']" is incompatible with "int"
PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

Comment: use a cast,`typing.cast`

Comment: In general you can use _overloads_ to give more information about the expected return type, so one overload would be `def f(x: Literal[0]) -> Literal[1]: ...`, but there's no way (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57855549/3001761) to say "all ints except 0".