# Python typing: overload based on length of tuple argument

Tags: python, mypy

I would like to add overloaded type annotations to an existing API that has semantics something like this:

```py
def f(x: Tuple[int, ...]) -> Union[int, List[int]]:
  if len(x) == 1:
    return x[0]
  return list(x)
```

The argument is a tuple, and the return type is either `int` or `List[int]` depending on whether the tuple has length 1.

To encode the output type's dependence on the input type, I've tried the following:

```py
from typing import overload, List, Tuple

@overload
def f(x: Tuple[int]) -> int: ...

@overload
def f(x: Tuple[int, ...]) -> List[int]: ...

def f(x: Tuple[int, ...]) -> Union[int, List[int]]:
  if len(x) == 1:
    return x[0]
  return list(x)
```

But when type-checked with mypy, this gives the following error:

```
script.py:4: error: Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

To address this I would need the second overload to have a type that indicates "tuples of any length except 1", but it seems that this sort of exclusive type doesn't exist ([PEP 484: exclusive type for type hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313872/pep-484-exclusive-type-for-type-hint)) What would be the best way to define overloaded annotations for this function?

Comment: Do you need the overload decorator or can you just do `def f(x: Tuple[int, ...]) -> int | List[int]:` You will either return an `int` or a `List[int]` because if I do `f(x=(1,))` is that still a variable-length tuple - i.e., `Tuple[int, ...]`?

Comment: The original function definition is essentially this (I used `Union[int, List[int]]` instead of `int | List[int]` for compatibility with older python versions). The question is how to do better than this, so that mypy can infer the correct non-unioned output type from the input.

Comment: It's OK. `mypy` is very strict about overload signatures, as type theory expects. It may sound weird for you, if you learned TypeScript before, that just eats almost any overload combination. In fact (it is an implementation detail, but remains true for a long time) `mypy` tries overloads in definitions order as well, so your code works as intended. Just put "type: ignore" on the error line. External callers will see the interface you want, see [this gist](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=6457ca299e67265563f7c03602819e65) (gist mine)

Comment: You may also want `def f(x: tuple[[]]) -> NoReturn` overload to prevent calling with empty tuple, if it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks - I removed special handling for zero-length tuples for the sake of a minimal repro. Regarding your previous comment, are you saying the recommended approach is to use what I wrote in my question and to tell mypy to ignore the error? If so would you like to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "overlap with incompatible return types" error message can sometimes be a little bit of a lint, as opposed to something broken. If you `# type: ignore`, mypy will still do what you want.

(I'm a maintainer of mypy)